# Prevent Facebook from grouping Open Graph actions in Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to read all the posts from my app using the graph path:
 `/me/home/filter=app_MY_APP_ID`.

Among the data returned, some of my actions are grouped together such as:

```js
actions =     (
            {
        link = "https://www.facebook.com/735475141/posts/10153036942300142";
        name = Comment;
    }
);
application =     {
    //deleted for app privacy
};
"created_time" = "2013-07-30T14:41:24+0000";
from =     {
    id = 735475141;
    name = "Can Poyrazo\U011flu";
};
id = "735475141_10153036942300142";
privacy =     {
    value = "";
};
type = link;
"updated_time" = "2013-07-30T14:41:24+0000";
}
```

When I go to my action (https://www.facebook.com/735475141/posts/10153036942300142) I see 4 photos grouped, with the story title 'X took 4 photos with MY_APP' which is great. But when I try to access that post object from Graph API, I'm getting only one post:

```js
{
  "id": "10153036942300142",
  "from": {
    "name": "Can Poyrazoğlu",
    "id": "735475141"
  },
  "start_time": "2013-07-29T17:46:22+0000",
  "end_time": "2013-07-29T17:46:22+0000",
  "publish_time": "2013-07-29T17:46:22+0000",
  "application": {
    //removed for privacy
  },
  "data": {
    "photo": {
      "id": "557831850941984",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10153036942105142",
      "type": //removed for privacy
      "title": ""
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

The 'grouped items' post that I see on the website appears to have reference to only one of the objects in that post at Graph API. How can I access all the actions, if possible, without grouping?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different endpoint: `/me/<app_namespace>:<action_name>`

This will return all actions published by your app for a given action and a given user. For example, using a user access token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/my_cooking_app:bake?access_token=...`

Comment: and that returns those actions only by me, while I am trying to read the feed from the user's scope (which contains posts by other users of my app who are friends of the current user).